# How to add Landscape monitoring to machine 0 in juju

Tags: juju, aws, landscape

The Juju Landscape charm supports adding relations to services, but there is no visible service in machine 0 to add a relation to. How to add it to Landscape then?

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to do it manually:

```
juju ssh 0
```

then follow the normal guide:

- https://help.landscape.canonical.com/GettingStarted/InstallingLandscapeClient/Draft